# Bash: How to use an alias command in combination with watch

Tags: bash, alias, watch

I would like to use an alias command in bash in combination with the watch command. The watch command is multiple chained commands.

A very simple example how I would think it would work (but it does not):

```
alias foo=some_command          # a more complicated command
watch -n 1 "$(foo) | grep bar"  # foo is not interpreted as the alias :(
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases

Comment: @Cyrus That won't help. @ PS Are you trying to say something specific?

Comment: @Socowi: You're right about that.

Comment: One more reason not to use aliases — use scripts instead

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I like aliases, because it makes my scrips shorter. I just define a long one-liner as a short alias and chain them. But of cause, I would agree not to overuse them

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`watch -n 1 "$(foo) | grep sh"` is wrong for two reasons.

1. When `watch "$(cmdA) | cmdB"` is executed by the shell, `$(cmdA)` [gets expanded](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) *before* running `watch`. Then `watch` would execute the *output* of `cmdA` as a command (which should fail in most cases) and pipe the output of that to `cmdB`. You probably meant `watch 'cmdA | cmdB'`.
2. The alias `foo` is defined in the current shell only. `watch` is not a built-in command and therefore has to execute its command in another shell which does not know the alias `foo`. There is a small trick presented in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25329/187122), however we have to make some adjustments to make it work with pipes and options

```
alias foo=some_command
alias watch='watch -n 1 ' # trailing space treats next word as an alias
watch foo '| grep sh'
```

Note that the options for `watch` have to be specified inside the `watch` alias. The trailing space causes *only the next word* to be treated as an alias. With `watch -n 1 foo` bash would try to expand `-n` as an alias, but not `foo`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. I will dive in the explanations tomorrow, though ;)

Answer (score 1):

I made a function that uses the `--color` option and allows you to use `-n` to specify a refresh interval.

```bash
swatch_usage() {
    cat <<EOF >&2
NAME
       swatch - execute a program periodically with "watch". Supports aliases.

SYNOPSIS
       swatch [options] command

OPTIONS
       -n, --interval seconds (default: 1)
              Specify update interval.  The command will not allow quicker than 0.1 second interval.
EOF
}

swatch() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        swatch_usage
        return 1
    fi
    seconds=1

    case "$1" in
    -n)
        seconds="$2"
        args=${*:3}
        ;;
    -h)
        swatch_usage
        ;;
    *)
        seconds=1
        args=${*:1}
        ;;

    esac

    watch --color -n "$seconds" --exec bash -ic "$args || true"
}
```

I only needed color and timing support but i'm sure you could add more if you wanted.

The meat of the function is that it executes your command with bash directly in interactive mode and can thus use any aliases or commands that are normally available to you in bash.

I'm not that experienced with scripting so fair warning, your mileage may vary. Sometimes i have to press `Ctrl+C` a few times to get it to stop, but for what it's worth, i've been using it frequently for 6 months without issue.

Gist form: https://gist.github.com/ablacklama/550420c597f9599cf804d57dd6aad131